# Imgur API - commercial charge for requests

Tags: imgur

I want to use Imgur API for commercial

By the following document

Imgur API: Pricing & Cost (imgur) | RapidAPI
https://rapidapi.com/imgur/api/imgur-9/pricing

1. For PRO
   requests 600000 / month
   uploads 60000 / month

   "requests 600000 / month" means the I can call 600000 API free in one month?
2. When I uploaded an image and got it's URL and published it to internet.
   The image access by much people (EX: More than 600000)
   Will I be charged for exceed requests? 
   Or the image access doesn't relative to requests, it's free?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> For PRO requests 600000 / month uploads 60000 / month
>
> "requests 600000 / month" means the I can call 600000 API free in one
> month?

Imgur API has a pro plan in which you can make 600,000 API calls/requests per month. However, if you exceed this limit, you'll be charged $0.001 per request.

For example, let's say you make 700,000 API requests in one month this means you have to pay $125 ($25 for 600,000 requests + $100 for 100,000 extra requests).

> When I uploaded an image and got it's URL and published it to
> internet. The image access by much people (EX: More than 600000) Will
> I be charged for exceed requests? Or the image access doesn't relative
> to requests, it's free?

Pro plan offers you 60,000 uploads per month with an extra $0.01 if you exceed this limit. You'll be charged only for requests and uploads nothing else.